# Minimizing absolute differences between n values under constraints on sums of these values

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have 15 unknown integer values $x_i$. I know that: $$\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i = 25 $$, $$\sum_{i=6}^{10} x_i = 32 $$ and $$\sum_{i=11}^{15} x_i = 41 $$
I wish to identify 15 integer $x_i$ that minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^{14} |x_{i+1} - x_i|$$ under these constraints. Is it possible? How should I proceed?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: integer $x{_i}$ thanks so much for your comment I will edit

Comment: My guess would be: $5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,9$. Hard to see how you can do better than $4$, since one of the values in the last five must be bigger than $8$ and one of the values in the first five must be $\leq 5$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{14} |x_{i+1}-x_i|\leq |\max x_i - \min x_i|$.

Comment: This answer is not unique, however: $5,5,5,5,5,\,5,5,6,8,8,\,8,8,8,8,9$

Comment: Whoops, inequality should be: $\sum_{i=1}^{14} |x_{i+1}-x_i|\geq |\max x_i - \min x_i|$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand. However, I was actually trying to build intuition to solve this problem more systematically in two dimensions, i.e finding N integer $x_{i,j}$ such that they are minimally spaced and such that the vector containing the sums of the $x_{i,j}$ on Y intervals of i and j are equal to some known vector Y'. Following your reasoning, I should identify the minimal possible distance under the constraints and then distribute the $x_{i,j}$ "manually", but I am confused on how to achieve that when N is large and there are more than 1 dimension.

Comment: Well, if you are interested in another question, you could also ask that question :) This is just the answer to the question you asked. While my solution looks manual, as you see in the full answer below, it's not "very manual."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show that $\sum_{i=1}^{14}|x_{i+1}-x_i|\geq |x_k-x_j|$ for any $j,k.$ It is trivially true if $j=k$. If $j<k$ then:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{14} |x_{i+1}-x_i|\geq\sum_{i=j}^{k-1} |x_{i+1}-x_i|\geq \left|\sum_{i=j}^{k-1} x_{i+1}-x_i\right|=|x_k-x_j|$$

If $j>k$ just reverse them.

Now, one of $x_{11},\dots,x_{15}$ must be at least $9$. And one of $x_{1},\dots,x_{5}$ must be at most $5$. So the we get that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{14}|x_{i+1}-x_i|\geq 4.$$

We can easily reach this minimum with $$(x_i)=(5,5,5,5,5,\quad6,6,6,7,7,\quad,8,8,8,8,9).$$

There's a more general rule than the above:

> **Lemma:** If $(x_i)_{i=1}^{N}$ is a sequence then:
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} |x_{i+1}-x_i|\geq \sum_{j=1}^{M-1} |y_{j+1}-y_{j}|$$ for any subsequence $(y_j)_{j=1}^{M}$ of $(x_i)$.

This more general result would be useful if you wanted $$x_1+\cdots+x_5=25\\ x_6+\cdots+x_{10}=41\\x_{11}+\cdots+{x_{15}}=32.$$

Then you'd know you had a subsequence $y_1,y_2,y_3$ such that $y_1\leq 5, y_2\geq 9,y_3\leq 6,$ so this lemma means that the we have:

$$\sum |x_{i+1}-x_{i}|\geq |5-9|+|9-6|=7$$

and we can get that value with $(5,5,5,5,5,\,8,8,8,8,9,\,7,7,6,6,6)$.

---

The general rule for generating a solution is, for each block, determine the average. If the average is an integer, we set each of the $x_i$ to that average. If the average in the block is not an integer, we can write the average as $m+\frac{k}{B}$ where $B$ is the size of the block, $m$ is and integer, and $1\leq k <B$. Then we can choose $k$ of the values as $m+1$ and $B-k$ values as $m$.

The only tricky part is when, for two blocks consecutive, if you have non-integers averages and the $m$ values are the same. Then which order you place the $x_i$ is dependent on the blocks around you.

For example, if you want: $$x_1+x_2+x_3=8\\x_{4}+x_{5}+x_{6}=7\\x_{7}+x_{8}+x_{9}=5$$

In this case, which order to put the $x_1,\dots,x_6$ is determined by the value if $5$ of the next block, so you have:

$$(x_i)=(2,3,3,\quad 3,2,2,\quad 2,2,1)$$

But if you wanted $x_{7}+x_{8}+x_{9}=10$ the you'd have:

$$(x_i)=(3,3,2,\quad 2,2,3,\quad 3,3,4)$$

Comment: It is indeed not too manual. Thank you, I did not know about this lemma. (I would vote for this comment but I can't).

Comment: If it is "enough of an answer" then you can select the checkbox by it, but don't do that if you are hoping for more answers/better answers.