# Minimizing distance between N real numbers in the 2 dim. plan under constraints on sums of these values

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

This post is an extension to the two dimension case of this solved problem: [Minimizing absolute differences between n values under constraints on sums of these values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456117/minimizing-absolute-differences-between-n-values-under-constraints-on-sums-of-th)

I have N unknown positive integer values $x_{i,j}$. I know that: $$\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=1}^5 x_{i,j} = a $$, $$\sum_{i=6}^{10}\sum_{j=6}^{10} x_{i,j} = b $$ ... and $$\sum_{i=N-4}^N\sum_{j=N-4}^{N} x_{i,j} = z $$ with a, b...z positive integers.
I wish to identify N integer $x_{i,j}$ that minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} |x_{i+1,j} - x_{i,j}| + |x_{i,j+1} - x_{i,j}| $$ under these constraints.

Would you have any idea on how to proceed?

Let me know if I should clarify.
Thank you very much for your help

EDIT: The $x_{i,j}$ could actually be real positive numbers.

Comment: I'm confused by this question. Are there no conditions on $x_{1,6}$, for example?

Comment: Hi again, I messed up with the sums, I am editing, sorry about that. The values of $x_{i,j}$ for i ranging from 1 to 6 and j from 1 to 6 should sum to a known a.

Comment: What, why is $i=1$ to $6$? What is a null value, as opposed to a zero value?

Comment: i ranges from 1 to 5, and I meant that any of these integers can be 0.

Comment: $i$ ranges from $6$ to $10$ in several of your sums, and $1$ to $N-1$ in the final sum.

Comment: I was correcting my previous comment. "The values of $x_{i,j}$ for i ranging from 1 to 5 and j from 1 to 5 should sum to a known a."